# Digital Surround (HDMI) Output

Tags: sound, intel-graphics, pulseaudio, hdmi

I recently built a HTPC and installed Ubuntu 12.10 on it.  It's a Shuttle XH61V with an onboard HDMI connection that I'm using to connect to the TV, which in turn connects to the speaker system (5.1).

I've tried everything I can find on this site and through Google but to no avail.  I've even tried installing Ubuntu 13.04, but that seems to present the exact same problem.

`pavucontrol` only shows "Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output" but no surround.  Running `speaker-test -c 6` seems to play to all speakers at once for the front speakers, quieter for the back speakers and not at all for LFE.

Since it's running through HDMI, I don't know if the fact that I'm using Intel HD graphics 4000 comes into play or not.

Here's my output for `aplay -L`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC662 rev1 Digital [ALC662 rev1 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I would be greatly appreciative of any help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure your TV is 5.1 capable? I have a similar setup as you, ie. htpc audio goes to TV and then from TV to my Harman Kardon, and although my TV is fairly recent, it does NOT support 5.1 HDMI since it only has 2 speakers, so it's impossible to get it to pass through 5.1 to my amp. The only way that works for me is using the spdif straight from the HTPC to my amp (since my amp does't have HDMI input).

Answer (score 2):

Open Sound Settings (Volume Controle), click the speaker icone - bottom of list[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVgSn.png)
On the last tab Configuration change profile for High Definition Controller,[image]
and choose the HDMI setting you want!
Then it will be available for selecting in the Output Device tab.
Happy Ubunting.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem as well, and it was fixed around ubutnu 15.10.  Using the most recent version might work, and you could try this with a 16.04 live CD.  Many hardware issues are fixed on more recent version.